# PySpark filter intersection of two columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, intersection

I have a PySpark DataFrame and I would like to filter it such that only rows where entries in `col_a` are present in `col_b` and vice versa. Example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("abc", "ddc", 1, 4.5),
        ("abb", "ddc", 4, 9.1),
        ("baa", "abc", 2, 3.2),
        ("abb", "bca", 1, 5.1),
        ("ddc", "abc", 2, 3.6),
        ("abc", "baa", 3, 2.6)
    ],
    ["col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d"]
)
```

This yields a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+                                                                                                                                                                                 
|col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  abc|  ddc|    1|  4.5|
|  abb|  ddc|    4|  9.1|
|  baa|  abc|    2|  3.2|
|  abb|  bca|    1|  5.1|
|  ddc|  abc|    2|  3.6|
|  abc|  baa|    3|  2.6|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So, what I would like is a Spark-y method to keep only rows where `col_a` is in `col_b`, or in other words, perform an intersection between `col_a` and `col_b`. My naive way of doing this is as follows:

```
col_a_and_col_b = (
    set(df.select("col_a").distinct().toPandas()["col_a"].tolist())
    .intersection(df.select("col_b").distinct().toPandas()["col_b"].tolist())
)

filtered_df = df.filter(
    (col("col_a").isin(col_a_and_col_b))
    & (col("col_b").isin(col_a_and_col_b))
)
```

(Here `col` is taken from `from pyspark.sql.functions import col`.) However, when working with large datasets, the variable `col_a_and_col_b` can be pretty large and then Spark sends that single variable out to all the nodes for processing. This strikes me as inefficient (and Spark does warn me about this), but I can't quite figure out a good way to do this. The result I'm looking for is:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  abc|  ddc|    1|  4.5|
|  baa|  abc|    2|  3.2|
|  ddc|  abc|    2|  3.6|
|  abc|  baa|    3|  2.6|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using self inner join to filter the common keys

```
df.join(df.selectExpr('col_b as col_a').dropDuplicates(), on='col_a')
```

Result

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  abc|  ddc|    1|  4.5|
|  baa|  abc|    2|  3.2|
|  ddc|  abc|    2|  3.6|
|  abc|  baa|    3|  2.6|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyspark **collect_list** then **array** functions for this case.

By using this method we are going to avoid getting all the column values as **`list`**.

**`Explaination:`**

- `collect_set(col("col_b")).over(w)` -> get all the distinct values and store into new column
- `arrays_overlap(array("col_b"), "cs_col_a")` -> check on `array_overlap` to get the distinct values.
- `filter` the true values based on above two columns

---

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *
w = Window.partitionBy(lit(1))
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("abc", "ddc", 1, 4.5),
        ("abb", "ddc", 4, 9.1),
        ("baa", "abc", 2, 3.2),
        ("abb", "bca", 1, 5.1),
        ("ddc", "abc", 2, 3.6),
        ("abc", "baa", 3, 2.6)
    ],
    ["col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d"]
)

df.withColumn("cs_col_b", collect_set(col("col_b")).over(w)).\
  withColumn("cs_col_a", collect_set(col("col_a")).over(w)).\
    withColumn("overlap_a", arrays_overlap(array("col_a"), "cs_col_b")).\
      withColumn("overlap_b", arrays_overlap(array("col_b"), "cs_col_a")).\
        filter(col("overlap_a") & col("overlap_b")).\
          drop(*['cs_col_b','cs_col_a','overlap_a','overlap_b']).\
    show(10,False)

#+-----+-----+-----+-----+
#|col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|
#+-----+-----+-----+-----+
#|abc  |ddc  |1    |4.5  |
#|baa  |abc  |2    |3.2  |
#|ddc  |abc  |2    |3.6  |
#|abc  |baa  |3    |2.6  |
#+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```